# Force lex to elicit specific slot

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I have multiple slots in my intent. Is it possible to force lex to elicit a specific slot using the aws sdk POSTTEXT call, and not worry about the priority of slots?

Example:

1. pizzaordering - intent
2. toppings - slot
3. pizzasize - slot
4. cheesequanity - slot
5. pizzaquantity - slot

When i post "25" to lex, i want it to match pizzaquantity instead of cheesequanity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliciting a specific slot needs to happen after Lex processes the input and sends the Event/Request to your Lambda Function during the "initialization and validation" code hook.

Without a Lambda Function, Lex will only `Delegate` which slots to elicit based on which ones are checked as required.

So to have more control like this, you will need a Lambda Function. You will want to read the [Lambda Function Input Event and Response Formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html). That shows you how Lex will pass the processed user input to your Lambda Function, and how to respond in certain ways so that you can tell Lex what to do next, such as `ElicitSlot`

To be clear, this is not done with the PostText API.

If you are already using a Lambda Function, then you can post the code you are using but want it to elicit a specific slot, then I could offer a more specific solution. If you don't use a Lambda Function yet, then try to set one up and you may see how to use `elicitSlot` yourself.

If you run into more problems, just ask another question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have any questions about my answer, just ask here and I'll be happy to help further.